# Retrieve the selected item of a dropdown to use it in a sentence that I will print in a textarea

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms, htmx

I have 3 dropdowns that work fine. My goal is to click on the button and print the text of the third dropdown inside the textarea (`def result` and `result.html`), precisely inside a sentence in `def test1`. For example if I select Madrid, I will print "The selected trip is Madrid".

[image]

I don't want to pass the sentence directly (with "Madrid" inside it) into `def result` (which is the function of `result.html`, i.e. of the textarea). I don't want the sentence construction (with "Madrid" in it) to be built inside the `def result` function

I want the text of the third dropdown (e.g. "Madrid"), to become a *placeholder* that is passed first in the `def test1` function. It is here that the sentence will be created which will subsequently be printed in the textarea (`def result`). I need this because in future in `def test1` I will also call other sentences from other python files. So it's like the `def test1` function acts as a sort of filter between the dropdowns and the textarea (`def result`).

I don't get any errors, but the sentence doesn't print. I think the problem is because `def test1` fails to retrieve `options` from the third dropdown (e.g. "Madrid").

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class City(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class FullRecord(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city_departure = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="city_departure")
    city_destination = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="city_destination")

    @property
    def departure_destination(self):
        return f"{self.city_departure}-{self.city_destination}"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.country.name
```

`views.py`

```
**from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import FullRecord, Country


def trip_selector(request):
    if "Hx-Request" in request.headers:
        trips = FullRecord.objects.none()
        if request.headers["Hx-Trigger"] == "id_trip":
            country_id = request.GET.get("country")
            if country_id != "":
                trips = FullRecord.objects.filter(country_id=country_id)
            return render(request, "trips.html", {"trips": trips})
        
        elif request.headers["Hx-Trigger"] == "id_extract_single_city":
            selected_trip = request.GET.get("trips")
            extracted_cities = []
            if selected_trip != "":
                trip = FullRecord.objects.get(id=int(selected_trip))
                trip_with_combined_names = trip.departure_destination
                split_trip = trip_with_combined_names.split("-")
                extracted_cities = split_trip
            return render(request, "extract_single_city.html", {"options": extracted_cities})
        
    else:
        countries = Country.objects.all()
        return render(request, "form.html", {"countries": countries})**
        
#Create sentence
def test1(request):
    sentence = ["The selected trip is ", "Congratulations you have selected the trip ", "You have currently selected travel ", "The currently selected trip is "]
    return f"{random.choice(sentence)} {options}" #ERROR????

#Print in textarea
def result(request):
    test_print_in_result = test1(request)
    return render(request,"result.html", {"test_print_in_result": test_print_in_result})
```

`urls.py`

```
**from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.trip_selector, name="trips")
]**
```

`admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from .models import Country, City, FullRecord

class Prossima(admin.ModelAdmin):
      list_display = ['id', 'country','departure_destination']
admin.site.register(FullRecord, Prossima)

admin.site.register(Country)
admin.site.register(City)
```

`base.html`:

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>University</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- HTMX -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.9.3/dist/htmx.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container mt-4">
        {% block  main-content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>

    <!-- evitare che le richieste hx-post incorrano in errori CSRF con le viste Django -->
    <script>
        document.body.addEventListener('htmx:configRequest', (event) => {
            event.detail.headers['X-CSRFToken'] = '{{ csrf_token }}'; //insert csrf token when performing AJAX request
        })
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

`forms.html`:

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %} 

{% block main-content %}
    <div class="flex justify-between px-10 gap-5 mt-5">
        <div class="flex flex-col w-full">
            <!-- First Combobox -->
            <label for="id_country">Country</label>

            <select name="country" id="id_country">
                <option value="">Please select</option>
                {% for country in countries %}
                    <option value="{{ country.pk }}">{{ country.name }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>

        
        <div class="flex flex-col w-full">
            <!-- Second Combobox ??????? (non lo so)-->
            <label for="id_trip">Trip</label>
            <select name="trips" id="id_trip"
                    hx-get="{% url 'trips' %}"
                    hx-include="[name=country]"
                    hx-indicator=".htmx-indicator"
                    hx-trigger="change from:#id_country">
            </select>
        </div>

        <!-- Third Combobox -->
        <div class="flex flex-col w-full">
            <label for="id_extract_single_city">Extract single city</label>
            <select name="extract_single_city" id="id_extract_single_city"
                    hx-get="{% url 'trips' %}"
                    hx-include="[name=trips]"
                    hx-indicator=".htmx-indicator"
                    hx-trigger="change from:#id_trip">

            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Textarea-->
    {% include "result.html" %}

    <!-- Button-->
    <button type="button" class="mybtn" name="btn" hx-get="{% url 'result' %}" hx-swap="outerHTML" hx-target="#id_result" hx-indicator=".htmx-indicator">Button 1</button>



{% endblock main-content %}
```

`trips.html`:

```html
<option value="">Please select</option>
{% for trip in trips %}
    <option value="{{ trip.id }}">{{ trip.city_departure }}-{{ trip.city_destination }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

**extract_single_city.html**

```
<option value="">Please select</option>
{% for i in options %}
    <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

`result.html`:

```html
<textarea name="result" id="id_result">{{ test_print_in_result }}</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite easy to implement actually.

Update `forms.html`:

The important part here is that you should define the textarea field rather than returning it as a seperate template (it's unnecessary). Also, include the value of the `extract_single_city` select field by referencing its id in `hx-include` attribute. I don't know if you want to be able to insert multiple messages into the textarea, I assumed you do that's why I changed the htmx swap technique to `beforeend` so the new result is added below the existing ones. I added `readonly` atribute to the textarea tag so it's not editable.

```
.....
<div class="flex flex-col w-1/2 justify-end">
    <button class="bg-green-300  p-2 rounded"
            type="button"
            hx-get="{% url 'result' %}"
            hx-include="#id_extract_single_city"
            hx-target="#id_result"
            hx-swap="beforeend">Submit
    </button>
</div>
<div class="py-2 px-10 h-96 mt-5">
    <textarea name="result" id="id_result" readonly class="w-full h-full rounded px-2 py-3"></textarea>
</div>
....
```

Update the `views`:

Please notice the `create_sentence` function is expecting a 'city' argument so it can create an appropriate sentence. You access the city value (supplied the htmx request) in the result function which returns an HttpResponse rather than a render function. This is because you don't need a template to return simple text.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create sentence
def create_sentence(request):
    sentence = random.choice(
        [
            "The selected trip is",
            "Congrats, you have selected the trip",
            "You have currently selected to travel",
            "The currently selected trip is",
        ]
    )
    city = request.GET.get("extract_single_city")
    return f"{sentence} {city} \n"

#Print in textarea
def result(request):
    result = create_sentence(request)
    return HttpResponse(result)
```

That should work.

**See example**
[image: Working example]

Comment: Yes, it was easy enough, my idea was this too, but being new to Django I had some doubts and I was wrong. I would like to ask you:
city = request.GET.get("extract_single_city") can ONLY be used in the def create_sentence function?

In the def result function I would need there to be only result = create_sentence.

I ask this because I should insert 60-70 stuff like city = request.GET.get("extract_single_city") and I would like to order them inside def create_sentence, so as to leave cleaner def result

Comment: You do that too. As long as you the request object into create_sentence function when you call it in result(), but it should hive same results. See the updated answer.

Comment: Yes, it seems to work, thanks a lot. I upvoted your answer. Two very simple questions: 1. To visualize the dropdowns and the textbox like you (to me they are all one below the other vertically) is it enough simply to intervene on the dropdowns with CSS or is there some trick like for Django forms?...2. When I print a sentence, I would like the previous one to be deleted. I tried using result.delete(0, 'end'), but it doesn't work. What can I use?

Comment: For styling my html, I'm using Tailwind CSS. You can simply include tailwindcss CDN in your base template and get the same styles as me. Or play around with the CSS to get the desired styles.

Comment: To replace the sentences in the textarea, just remove the hx-swap attribute. The default behaviour of htmx is to replace the innerHTML of the element making the request with the response it gets.

Comment: OK perfect. I have another question, again out of curiosity. Probably in the future I will have to write the sentences in external python files, so as to sort the type of sentence by file. So for example I will have the def create_sentence function in an external python file.

The question is: inside the function in an external file, can I safely use city = request.GET.get("extract_single_city") to retrieve the dropdown selection?

So the logic is: compose the sentence (including the placeholder retrieved from the dropdown) in an external file, then pass it in def result

Comment: As long as you're using create_sentence() to handle a request object AND you're always accessing the 'extract_single_city' value, the function should work regardless of which file it is in.

Comment: Fine, but let's continue chatting. I have to tell you something :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255178/discussion-between-horiatiki-and-mcpherson).

Comment: I didn't see the chat notification. I replied to you in chat. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

example from my project
(forms.py)

```
quantity_choices = (
    (i+1,i+1) for i in range(10)
                    ) 
class add_to_cart(forms.Form):
        quantity = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=quantity_choices, label="Quantity:")
```

to get the info (views.py)

```
def viewsomething(request)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = add_to_cart(request.POST)
        if request.user.is_authenticated and form.is_valid():
            quantity = int(form.cleaned_data['quantity']) #now do something with this data
    else:
        form = add_to_cart()
        context = {"form": form,}
        return render(blahblah)
```

and in html just say {{form}}

ps remeber to add a sumbit button

but tbh its really easy to get this info so not sure why you asked

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/